# Where can I find a jQuery color animation plugin?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, colors, animation

I need an up-to-date jQuery color animation plugin that works in IE 8. I tried using the one at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color but it causes errors like "Invalid property value." in the following line of code from color.js:

```
fx.elem.style[attr] = "rgb(" + [
    Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[0] - fx.start[0])) + fx.start[0]), 255), 0),
    Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[1] - fx.start[1])) + fx.start[1]), 255), 0),
    Math.max(Math.min( parseInt((fx.pos * (fx.end[2] - fx.start[2])) + fx.start[2]), 255), 0)
].join(",") + ")";
```

Where can I get something that works?

By the way, I *really* hate IE, if that helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't help.  (However, so do I)

Comment: I know. I'm just looking for opportunities to say that I hate IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), which enables color animation.

Comment: Can I just include the color animation stuff without importing the other ui stuff?

Comment: I believe you can build a custom download with nothing but Core.

Comment: Seems to work so far. It took a minute or two to try - IE just crashed :)